# How to do something different with first element in each loop?

Tags: jquery, each

Within an each() loop, is it possible to do something with the first element in particular, not the next ones? Something like this:

```
$( '.selector').each(function(){
    // if first element found, do something
});
```

Comment: why not `$('.selector').first()` rather than iterate over whole set?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('.selector').each(function(i, el){
    if ( i === 0) {
       // Will be done to first element.
    }

});
```

Comment: i would be 0 not 1 for first element

Comment: Oops, My Bad. Updated.

Comment: Because the answer was wrong.  I have removed it now.

Answer (score 6):

You could determine if it is the first element by checking the index.

```
$('.selector').each(function(i, el) {
    if (i === 0) {
       // first element.. use $(this)
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could also just access the first element *outside* of the loop using the [`.first()` method](http://api.jquery.com/first/):

```
$('.selector').first();
```

The [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) would also work:

```
$('.selector:first');
```

Comment: i would be 0 for first element not 1.

Answer (score 4):

As variant, like this

```
$( '.selector').each(function(index, element) {
   if (index === 0) {
      // if first element found, do something
   }
});
```

Or use

```
$( '.selector:first')
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/nowubo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 3):

Probably not as efficient as it could be but it's straightforward:

```
$( '.selector').each(function(index){
  if (index === 0) {
    // first element found, do something
  }
});
```